# Ms Access 2013 Database

Tags: ms-access

I have create a database in which table name is Approved_schedule which has column name is FileNo, stdName, Amount1, Amount2, and I want to add Amount column in Query process I have written this query.

for example: FileNo = 7100, Amount1 = 19430 and Aoumnt2 = 0;

```
Select SUM(Amount1 + Amount2) AS 'Total Payment'
from Approved_schedule 
where FileNo = 7100;
```

But this Query result is Total Payment = 0;

What should I do?

Comment: i am write this query but result will be null SELECT SUM(Amount1 + Amount2)
from Payments
where [File No]=7100
Group by [File No];

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by if you're doing a sum.

```
Group By FileNo
```

Comment: i am write this query but result will remain null SELECT SUM(Amount1 + Amount2)
from Payments
where [File No]=7100
Group by [File No];